# Prove that numbers relatively prime to $n$ are congruent modulo $n$ to powers of primitive root of $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function, primitive-roots

> Suppose that we have $\gcd(a,n) = 1$ where $a$ is primitive root of $n$ and $\{a_1, a_2 .. a_{\phi(n)} \}$ are numbers less than $n$ which are relative prime to it. Show that this set of numbers is congruent modulo $n$ to $\{a, a^2 ... a^{\phi(n)}\}$

I know that all powers upto $\phi(n)$ of primitive root are incongruent modulo $n$ to each other, but cannot prove this theorem. Hints are welcome!

**Edit:**

The definition of primitive root that I know is:

> Primitive root is an integer $a$ so that $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 (\mathrm{mod} \ n)$ and $a^{k} \not \equiv 1 (\mathrm{mod} \ n)$ for all $k < \phi(n)$

Comment: What if not this property is your definition of *primitive root*?

Comment: @Hagen Primitive root is an integer $a$ so that $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 (\mathrm{mod} \ n)$ and $a^{k} \not \equiv 1 (\mathrm{mod} \ n)$ for all $k < \phi(n)$

Comment: Well, you have two finite sets of $\phi(n)$ elements, and both sets contain pairwise incongruent residue classes modulo $n$ that are relatively prime to $n$, of which there is a total of $\phi(n)$. Seems immediate, unless the issue you have is showing that $a$, $a^2,\ldots,a^{\phi(n)}$ are pairwise incongruent, in which case you can do that by showing that if $a^i \equiv a^{i+k}\pmod{n}$ with $k\geq 0$, then $1\equiv a^k\pmod{n}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin makes complete sense, Thanks a lot!